# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!}{n^n} x^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I'm trying find out where $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!}{n^n} x^n$ converges.
First I found that the radius of convergence is $R=e$, but after that I had difficulty testing convergence at $x=\pm e$.

I'd be grateful for some hints.

Comment: Try Stirling aproximation... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Show that $$n^n e^{1 - n} < n!$$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n \geq 2$. Does this tell you anything about the series?